# React tsParticles (fireworks) not working

Tags: reactjs, particles

I'm trying to use [react-tsParticle](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/blob/main/components/react/README.md). I'm interested in the "Fireworks preset" but unfortunately that is not working.
I've seen some examples like [this codepen one](https://codepen.io/chock1/pen/YzQwmjO).
But If I use that option/config that doesn't work. it created some fireworks blasts in the bottom but it's useless [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/1qvx7uc).

If I use like that `codepen` example it works. But that's not how it is meant to be used in react. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this options :

```
const options = {
preset: "fireworks",
sounds: {
  enable: true,
},
particles: {
  move: {
    speed: 1,
  },
},
interactivity: {
  detectsOn: "canvas",
  events: {
    resize: true,
    click: {
      enable: true,
      mode: "push",
    },
  },
},
maxParticles: 3,
fpsLimit: 60,
emitters: [
  {
    direction: "top",
    life: {
      count: 1000,
      duration: 0.2,
      delay: 1,
    },
  },
],
};
```